# Why did Mordo introduce this character this way?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange In The Multiverse of Madness*, Mordo introduces a group of heroes to Doctor Strange. One of the heroes is

> Black Bolt

but instead of just saying his name, he says a garbled version of the name, similar to pig latin. Going off of memory, I believe the name he used was

> Bladagack Badagolt.

Doctor Strange responded in kind with a similarly garbled greeting. What was the significance of introducing the character this way? *(Or is my memory completely mangled and I apparently had a mini-stroke?)*

Comment: "Oh, we're using our made-up names"

Comment: Punishment for people who couldn't bring themselves to sit through the *Inhumans* show?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is his name.

From the [marvel cinematic wiki.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Bolt)

> Blackagar Boltagon, also known as Black Bolt, is the leader of the Inhuman Royal Family and the King of the Inhumans of Attilan.

Mordo was just being polite by introducing Black Bolt by his real name, which is not a secret.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks! Am I correct that Doctor Strange responded with something somewhat silly then, or did I misremember that?

Comment: In some ways, that is even worse.

Comment: @DavidK Strange replies by asking "Blackagar Boltagar?" though he may not actually have misheard it--he may have just been being an ass.

Comment: @Exal "*he may have just been being an ass.*" - I mean, that's pretty on-brand

Answer (score 8):

From the Disney+ subtitles, the dialogue is:

> Mordo: Blackagar Boltagon. Keeper of the Terrigen Mists, the Inhuman king.
>
> Strange: Blackagar Boltagard? Huh. Hidigy hidithere.

Mordo introduces him in this way, because it is his actual name. "Black Bolt" is his superhero name. This is shown at the top of his [marvel.com character page](https://www.marvel.com/characters/black-bolt).

Strange replies in that way, the first part because he misheard, the second part because he is an ass.